# What fallocate() does?

Tags: c, linux, unix, filesystems

Actually, I have two questions.

#### What `fallocate()` does?

I read the man page and have the following understanding. For filesystems that support hole in file, `fallocate()` is used to punch holes and allocate new spaces in the file. For filesystems without holes, `fallocate()` can only be used to allocate new space after the end of file, i.e., it only has effect when `len + offset > file_size`.

Is my understanding correct? If so, I also have the following question.

#### `fallocate()` vs `ftruncate()` when extending file

Now I want to create a new file and allocate a specific size of zero-filled bytes in the file. I realized that both `fallocate()` and `ftruncate()` can do the job. What's their difference?

BTW, I know that `fallocate()` is not portable, but since my program is only for Linux, portability to other Unix-like systems is not taken into consideration.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [posix_fallocate(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_fallocate.3.html) in your code. The difference with [ftruncate(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ftruncate.2.html) is that (on file systems supporting it, e.g. Ext4) disk space is indeed reserved by `posix_fallocate` but `ftruncate` extends the file by adding holes (and without reserving disk space).

E.g. if you disk is 100Gbytes, and you `posix_fallocate` a 5Gb file, you'll see (with `df`) that available space has reduced (since before the call); if you did only an `ftruncate` you won't see available space reducing.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31424315/841108) to a related question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is allocating the whole file at once better than make a big hole and writing data page by page?

Comment: It depends what you want (and of your system & configuration). And if you care that much, benchmark!

Comment: wait why do we need fallocate? we can just do a write/pwrite at the end of the file right? what does fallocate provide in addition?

Comment: Erben Mo: fallocate is usefull for example if you want mmap file.