# File Holes and Shared Memory in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, file, memory

Since I read the Linux Programming Interface book (very good read) I discovered the file holes in Linux. Therefore using Unix file formats like Ext4 one can open a new file write 1000 bytes seek to the position of 1000.000.000 write another 1000 bytes and depending the block size of the file format end up with a file consuming just 2048 bytes for a block size of 1024 or 512.

So basically the file is created as a 1GB + 1000 bytes long file where only two blocks of real drive space are used.

Can I erase the middle of a file forcing the system to deallocate those blocks on the drive?

Is there an equivalent where I allocate (shared memory) with or without a file backing it where it has also holes that are just filled as the memory pages are written?

Would be nice to allocate 1GB shared memory but never utilize it fully until necessary just to avoid remapping if the shared memory block should grow.

Comment: Don't ask several questions. And show the source code relevant to your question.

Comment: Universality of I/O is a core principle and therefore having holes in I/O resources and mapping those streams to memory is virtually the same. Those two questions are just related to the concept hole within a medium. It is a file descriptor you use to share memory (as far as I remember) and why should there be code? Another aspect I do not understand.

Comment: No, some file systems do not permit any holes.

Comment: They are filled with zeros transparently as holes are defined to appear on read if they exist.

Comment: This is wrong for some versions of NFS and for VFAT

Comment: The the Linux Interface book is lying or at least flawed in that regard. What happens in those cases?

Comment: I don't know, ask another question with some C code. I voted to close this question, since it is unclear and/or too broad. You should ask more focused questions showing some code in them.

Comment: I think it is perfectly suited it is regarding to the effects of holes in file description and the answer seams to be that memory is a medium that seam to does not support holes at all but fills it with zeros leading to actually consumption of memory. I hoped Linux is smart enough to fill it with holes in the paging file or virtual memory (so to speak). 

Since you raised the issue of eventually formats that support no holes and not filling in zeros (consuming actual space) and answered I do not know, I do not know if your original issue is correct.

Comment: Wrong. It is a matter of file system & swap area, not of medium. Raw mediums (magnetic tapes, floppy disks, USB keys, hard disks, SSD disks) don't have any holes (except of course the punched cards of 1960s). Holes are a software artifact (provided by the file system)

Comment: It is a matter of page table and the process's page table. Since Fat systems work similar by allocating blocks and assign those to fat entries I hoped this might be true for memory but up to now it seams not. Maybe I ask a kernel dev about it.

Comment: Wrong again. You really seems confused.

Comment: I feel you get picky about this issue by referring to holes of punched cards so I guess its time for you to cool down first. Let's see what other people contribute.

Comment: No, the point is that holes in files is a file system software artifact. Raw block devices don't have any hole!

Comment: Exactly. Since we format anything and the page table can be seen as such the question was if the memory 'file format' of Linux supports this and the answer seams to be no.

Comment: The answer (to what question exactly?) probably depends upon the file system and your actual computer. Other people might contribute by voting to close your question (too broad, unclear, several questions in one, no source code shown, ....)

Comment: Question title includes ***"and Everything"***??  You really want us to work on a question about ***"everything"***??

Comment: This is just a typical addition. Like a film about a lonely person finding their love and everything... . It is still love related but has to do with the wider picture. So in this regard it was ment to focus on the complete picture rather than what ever... .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I erase the middle of a file forcing the system to deallocate those blocks on the drive?

You probably want the Linux specific [fallocate(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html); beware, it might not work on some filesystems (e.g. NFS, VFAT, ...), because some [filesystems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) don't have holes. See also [lseek(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html) with `SEEK_HOLE`, [posix_fadvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html), [madvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html), [memfd_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/memfd_create.2.html), etc...

Raw [block devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file#BLOCKDEV) (like a disk partition, or an USB key, or an SSD) don't have any holes (but you could `mmap` into them). Holes are a file system software artifact.

> Would be nice to allocate 1GB shared memory but never utilize it

this is contradictory. If the memory is *shared* it is *used* (by the thing -generally another process- with which you *share* that memory). Read [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) if you really want [shared memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory) (and read *carefully* [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)). Read more about [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), [address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space), [paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging), [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit)s, [page faults](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault), [operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system),  [kernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28operating_system%29), [mmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap), [demand paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demand_paging), [copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write), [memory map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_map), [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format), [sparse files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file) ... Try also the `cat /proc/$$/maps` command in a terminal, and understand the output (see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)...).

Perhaps you want to pre-allocate some address space range, and later really allocate the virtual memory. This is possible using Linux version of [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html).

To pre-allocate a gigabyte memory range, you'll first call `mmap` with `MAP_NORESERVE`

```
size_t onegiga = 1L<<30;
void* startad = mmap(NULL, onegiga, PROT_NONE, 
                MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE|MAP_SHARED,
                -1, 0);
if (startad==MAP_FAILED) { perror("mmap MAP_NORESERVE"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
void* endad = (char*)startad + onegiga;
```

The `MAP_NORESERVE` does not consume a lot of resources (i.e. does not eat swap space, which is not reserved, hence the name of the flag). It is pre-allocating address space, in the sense that further `mmap` calls (without `MAP_FIXED`) won't give an address inside the returned range (unless you `munmap` some of it).

Later on, you can allocate some subsegment of that, in multiples of the page size (generally 4Kbytes), using `MAP_FIXED` inside the previous segment, e.g.

```
size_t segoff = 1024*1024; // or something else such that ....
assert (segoff >=0  && segoff < onegiga && segoff % sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)==0);
size_t segsize = 65536; // or something else such that ....
assert (segsize > 0 && segsize % sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)==0 
        && startad + segoffset + segsize < endad);
void* segmentad = mmap(startad + segoffset, segsize,
                       PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, 
                       MAP_FIXED | MAP_PRIVATE, 
                       -1, 0);
if (segmentad == MAP_FAILED) { perror("mmap MAP_FIXED"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
```

This re-allocation with `MAP_FIXED` will use some resources (e.g. consume some swap space).

IIRC, the [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/) runtime and garbage collection uses such tricks.

Read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and carefully [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and the particular man pages of relevant system calls.

Read also about [memory overcommitment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_overcommitment). This is a Linux feature that I dislike and generally disable (e.g. thru [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)).

BTW, the [Linux kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software). You can download its source code from [kernel.org](http://kernel.org/) and study the source code. And you can write some experimental code also. Then ask another more focused question showing your code and the results of your experiments.

Comment: > this is contradictory. If the memory is shared it is used (by the thing -generally another process- with which you share that memory). <

I thought this is a mapping between a page table and actual memory but I see the problem. If the memory would not be allocated in first hand a special mechanism must exist to notify each party which memory block is intended to fill that hole in the mapping.

What happens if I map a file in memory and it has holes? How does fit the picture?

Comment: "What happens if I map a file in memory and it has holes?" this is yet another question, and it depends how you call `mmap`

Comment: Then tell me or point me to some resources. What happens... .

Comment: `mmap(2)` has some answers. If it is unclear, ask another question showing the code that you have tried.

Comment: I noticed. I have read Advanced Linux Programming (2001 version) recently since it is available for free. I read those man pages regarding shared memory several times during the last week since I am investigating some possibilities. I never found anything regarding holes.

Comment: You really should ask a *separate* question and give the code that you have tried and experimented.