# what is the most reliable command to find actual size of a file linux

Tags: linux, unix

Recently I tried to find out the size of a file using various command and it showed huge differences.

`ls -ltr` showed its size around 34GB (bytes rounded off by me ) while
du -sh filename showed it to be around 11GB. while 
stat command showed the same to be around 34GB . 
Any idea which is the most reliable command to find actual size of the file ?

There was some copy operation performed on it and we are unsure of if this was appropriately done as after a certain time source file from where copy was being performed was removed by a job of ours.

Comment: I guess that is a sparse file, du tells its current disk usage, ls its declared size (that might be reached if you modify the file decreasing the runs of blank blocks)

Comment: Even so seems unusually out of proportion, although anything is possible i guess.

Comment: @l'L'l: Why so unusual? `$ truncate -s 10T foo; ls -l foo; du -sh foo` will give `10995116277760` and `0`.

Comment: @rodrigo, Actually, what I meant is that it would be unusual if the file in question was not sparse, or there was major discrepancy between `ls -lsh` and `du -h; du -bh`. The example you've shown gives an apparent file size and an actual file size, so of course it's going to be completely different.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is no inaccuracy or reliability issue here, you're just comparing two different numbers: logical size vs physical size.

Here's [Wikipedia's illustration for sparse files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file):

[image: Elaborate illustration better explained by the Wikipedia Article]

`ls` shows the gray+green areas, the logical length of the file. `du` (without `--apparent-size`) shows only the green areas, since those are the ones that take up space.

You can create a sparse file with `dd count=0 bs=1M seek=100 of=myfile`.

`ls` shows 100MiB because that's how long the file is:

```
$ ls -lh myfile
-rw-r----- 1 me me 100M Jul 15 10:57 myfile
```

`du` shows 0, because that's how much data it's allocated:

```
$ du myfile
0 myfile
```

Comment: Also, some filesystems may store the data compressed, making the difference even more so.

Comment: Just note that this does not really answer the literal question posted, although this is likely what the user needed to know

Comment: The explicit answer to the literal question is "all the commands are equally reliable".

Comment: @rodrigo On which compressing file systems does `du` show post-compression blocks? On btrfs it shows pre-compression blocks.

Comment: @thatotherguy: I'll do a few experiments if I got the time. But from the top of my head, I think that ZFS and maybe also ext4 did that.

Comment: I actually used du -sh filename command and not just du filename

Comment: @thatotherguy Please add a white background to your images, as when I use stackexchanges Dark Theme, the black on what-should-be-white background does not show through properly. I speculate you obtained it from the original image in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file#/media/File:Sparse_file_(en).svg which has an alpha that allows the background (black in the case of the dark theme) to show through. So not completely "your fault" here.

Answer (score 4):

```
ls -l --block-size=M
```

will give you a long format listing (needed to actually see the file size) and round file sizes up to the nearest `MiB`.

If you want `MB` (10^6 bytes) rather than `MiB` (2^20 bytes) units, use `--block-size=MB` instead.

If you don't want the `M` suffix attached to the file size, you can use something like `--block-size=1M`. Thanks Stéphane Chazelas for suggesting this.

This is described in the man page for `ls`; `man ls` and search for `SIZE`. It allows for units other than `MB/MiB` as well, and from the looks of it (I didn't try that) arbitrary block sizes as well (so you could see the file size as number of 412-byte blocks, if you want to).

Note that the `--block-size` parameter is a GNU extension on top of the Open Group's `ls`, so this may not work if you don't have a GNU userland (which most Linux installations do). The ls from GNU coreutils 8.5 does support `--block-size` as described above.

Answer (score 3):

There are several notions of file size, as explained in [that other guy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31437673/841108) and the wikipage figure on [sparse files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file).

However, you might want to use both [ls(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) & [stat(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) commands.

If coding in C, consider using [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) & [lseek(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html) syscalls.

See also the references in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31424315/841108).