# what's the difference between fallocate and ftruncate

Tags: c, linux, glibc, fallocate

They can all change file size according to my test. 
why can they all change file to larger and to shorter?
what's the difference between fallocate and ftruncate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What fallocate() does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22820139/what-fallocate-does)

Comment: Also see [fallocate vs posix_fallocate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14063046/608639)

Answer (score 10):

`ftruncate` is a simple, single-purpose function.  [Per the POSIX documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ftruncate.html), it simply sets the file to the requested length:

> If `fildes` refers to a regular file, the `ftruncate()` function shall cause the size of the file to be truncated to `length`.  ...

`ftruncate()` is also a standard POSIX function and is portable.  Note that POSIX does not specify *how* an OS sets the file length, such as whether or not a file set to any length is [a sparse file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file).

[`fallocate()` is a Linux-specific function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html) that does a lot more, and in very specific ways:

> **Allocating disk space**
>
> The default operation (i.e., mode is zero) of fallocate() allocates
>          the disk space within the range specified by `offset` and `len`.  The
>          file size (as reported by `stat(2)`) will be changed if `offset+len` is
>          greater than the file size.  Any subregion within the range specified
>          by offset and len that did not contain data before the call will be
>          initialized to zero.  This default behavior closely resembles the
>          behavior of the `posix_fallocate(3)` library function, and is intended
>          as a method of optimally implementing that function.
>
> ...
>
> **Deallocating file space**
>
> Specifying the `FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE` flag (available since Linux
>          2.6.38) in mode deallocates space (i.e., creates a hole) in the byte
>          range starting at `offset` and continuing for `len` bytes.  Within the
>          specified range, partial filesystem blocks are zeroed, and whole
>          filesystem blocks are removed from the file.  After a successful
>          call, subsequent reads from this range will return zeroes.
>
> ...
>
> **Collapsing file space**
>
> Specifying the `FALLOC_FL_COLLAPSE_RANGE` flag (available since Linux
>          3.15) in mode removes a byte range from a file, without leaving a
>          hole.  The byte range to be collapsed starts at `offset` and continues
>          for `len` bytes.  At the completion of the operation, the contents of
>          the file starting at the location `offset+len` will be appended at the
>          location offset, and the file will be `len` bytes smaller.
>
> ...
>
> **Zeroing file space**
>
> Specifying the `FALLOC_FL_ZERO_RANGE` flag (available since Linux 3.15)
>          in mode zeroes space in the byte range starting at `offset` and
>          continuing for `len` bytes.  Within the specified range, blocks are
>          preallocated for the regions that span the holes in the file.  After
>          a successful call, subsequent reads from this range will return
>          zeroes.
>
> ...
>
> **Increasing file space**
>
> Specifying the `FALLOC_FL_INSERT_RANGE` flag (available since Linux
>          4.1) in mode increases the file space by inserting a hole within the
>          file size without overwriting any existing data.  The hole will start
>          at `offset` and continue for `len` bytes.  When inserting the hole inside
>          file, the contents of the file starting at `offset` will be shifted
>          upward (i.e., to a higher file offset) by `len` bytes.  Inserting a
>          hole inside a file increases the file size by `len` bytes.
>
> ...

Answer (score 1):

With ftruncate you tell linux the size you want this file to be.
It will truncate extra space if the file is getting shorter (including freeing up disk space) or add zeros, allocating disk space if you make the file longer.

fallocate is a general purpose function to effect change to a range to bytes belonging to a file.

Depending on how you use fallocate, you can accomplish everything you could with ftruncate with fallocate. Its just a little more complicated as you will have to know which range you need to allocate/deallocate (initial offset+length).

With fallocate you can pre allocate disk space without logically growing a file (example a zero byte file at the ls level that uses 1GB).

I just wrote a C program to perform high performance gzipping of a file with direct I/O using fallocate and ftruncate. I use fallocate to pre-allocate 64MB at a time to the file. In the end I use ftruncate to trim the excess space allocated.

Works perfectly with XFS, I confirmed ftruncate actually frees disk space with xfs_bmap -vp on a few files.

Answer (score 0):

**fallocate** is used to preallocate blocks to a file

The following command will allocate a file with a size of 1GB.

```
fallocate -l 1G test_file1.img
```

**ftruncate** - set a file to a specified length

```
ftruncate(fileno(fout),size);
```

Comment: fallocate has multiple purposes, you oversimplified it.

Answer (score 0):

As I now know:  
1.fallocate can't change file to shorter. it  add actual space to file.  
2.ftruncate add len to "describe", just like declaration.