# mmap on file with holes

Tags: c, mmap

I am experimenting with mmap in following way, but I can not understand if it is correct:

```
#include <fcntl.h>  // open
#include <unistd.h> // ftuncate
#include <sys/mman.h>   // mmap

#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>


int main(){
    off_t const size = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
    const char *filename = "testfile";

    int fd = open(filename, O_RDWR | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, 0644);
    ftruncate(fd, size);

    char *mem = (char *) mmap(nullptr, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, /* offset */ 0);

    const char *msg = "Hello";

    memcpy(&mem[100], msg, strlen(msg));

    memcpy(&mem[200], msg, strlen(msg));

    memcpy(&mem[4 * 1024 * 1024], msg, strlen(msg));
}
```

As long I understand, `ftruncate` create a file with hole. Isn't this a problem for `mmap` later?

Will this work on 10 GB file on 64 bit system?

On Linux shall I use `fallocate(fd, FALLOC_FL_ZERO_RANGE, 0, 8 * size)` or there is no significant difference in speed?

Comment: sorry for example, I used C++ compiler there

Comment: `mmap()` works fine with files with holes. It deals with the logical data, not the physical disk blocks.

Comment: so it "refill" the holes and finally all data is stored on the disk correctly?

Comment: does fseek / fwrire works fine as well?

Comment: Everything works the same. Holes in files are just an optimization, they have no effect on how you access the file.

Comment: @Barmar not fully agree, but may be my example is very specific - linux swapfiles and things like that. Thanks.

Comment: I added a link to the difference between fallocate and ftruncate in my answer.

Comment: @Barmar: They have some effect: writes to holes can `SIGBUS` if there's `ENOSPC` on the device. You want `posix_fallocate` to handle this synchronously rather than via a nasty signal.

Comment: Right, the purpose of `fallocate()` is to ensure that space is reserved for the holes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Holes in files have no effect on any normal file operations, they're just an optimization in the way the file is stored on disk. As far as any operations like reading, seeking, memory mapping, etc. are concerned, it's just a long series of zero bytes. The filesystem driver takes care of turning the hole into a block of zeroes when reading the relevant pages into memory.

For the difference between `fallocate()` and `ftruncate()`, see [what's the difference between fallocate and ftruncate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49360932/whats-the-difference-between-fallocate-and-ftruncate)